# Matplotlib bar plot width only changing width of last bar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this barplot and changing with width value is only changing the width of the very last bar. I've attached the picture and code. Anyone know why?

```
indexes = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 2
pdb.set_trace()
plt.bar(indexes, values, width=2, color="blueviolet")
plt.xlabel("Phenotype identifier", fontdict=font)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Because your bars over laps with each other and your data happens to be monotonically increasing, see, if you (suppose `indexes=range(10)`):

```
plt.bar(indexes, range(10)[::-1], width=2, color="blueviolet")  #indexes should be indices
```

you'll get:

[image]

Comment: Oh okay... good catch! I don't want them to do that thought haha. How can I fix that?

Comment: @jcam77 - You're defining the left corner locations to be strictly 1 unit apart.  Just do `indexes = np.arange(0, 2*len(labels), 2)`.

Comment: Thanks @JoeKington. I added that but they are still the same width.